# ajax form submit to php file and to url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a subscribe form in wordpress that (currently) only has the ability to add submitted email to a custom post type (`subscribers`) and show it in backend.I am wondering how to also have this functionality, and send this email to a custom url (concretely to APSIS).

So I have a form

```
<form id="subscribe" class="subscribe_form" name="subscribe_form" action="#" method="post">
    <input name="subscriber_email" class="subscriber_email" placeholder="Your mail here">
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My save custom post type function that gets executed via AJAX

```
<?php 

add_action('wp_ajax_save_subscriber', 'save_subscriber');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_save_subscriber', 'save_subscriber');

if (!function_exists('save_subscriber')) {
    function save_subscriber() {

        if (isset($_POST['subscriber_email']) && is_email($_POST['subscriber_email'])) {
            global $wpdb;
            $post_data = array(
                'post_type' => 'subscribers',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            );
            $published_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
            add_post_meta($published_id, 'subscriber_email', $_POST['subscriber_email']);
            $out = 'OK';
        } else{
            $out = 'ERROR';
        }

        die($out);
    }
}
```

And my AJAX

```
$('#subscribe').submit(function() {
    'use strict';
    var str = $(this).serialize() + '&action=save_subscriber';
    var $form = $(this);
    var $wrapper = $(this).parent();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: custom.ajaxurl,
        data: str,
        success: function(msg){
            if( msg === 'OK' ) {
                $form.animate({ height: '0px' }, 800, function() {
                    $form.hide();
                });
                $wrapper.find('.success_message').delay(400).html(custom.success).slideDown(600);
            }else {
                $wrapper.find('.subscriber_email').addClass('field_error').attr('placeholder', custom.error_mail).val('').focus();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Now I have some more wrappers, and noonce field etc. but that's not important here.

This works fine when you want to just add a post to the CPT, but I need to submit this to

```
http://www.anpdm.com/public/process-subscription-form.aspx?formId=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I got the id and everything from the client, now I need to implement this.

I've seen something about curl, but I've never done anything with it, so I don't really know where to start. Since my action is pointing to my `save_subscriber()` function I recon that in that function I'd also have to add a way to send this form to the required url. But how?

Any info will help, thanks.

### ANSWER

So following the answer provided by silver, I managed to get it working.

```
#Run CURL
$url = 'http://www.anpdm.com/public/process-subscription-form.aspx?formId=xxxxxxxxxx';

$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $request, array (
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $custom_query_string,
));
$response = curl_exec($request);
$response_data = curl_getinfo($request);
curl_close($request);

#END CURL
if ($response_data['http_code'] == 200) {
    $out = 'OK';
}
```

The `formId` is the form number specific for this user, and the `$custom_query_string` conformed to the form provided by APSIS and contained something like this:

```
pf_Email=$_POST['email']&
Submit=Prenumerera&
pf_DeliveryFormat=HTML&
pf_MailinglistName1=xxxxx&
pf_FormType=OptInForm&
pf_OptInMethod=SingleOptInMethod&
pf_CounterDemogrFields=0&
pf_CounterMailinglists=1&
pf_AccountId=xxxx&
pf_ListById=1&
pf_Version=2
```

After that all worked, I get my subscribers in the wordpress backend, and they appear in the APSIS console where the users are :)

I guess I needed user_agent and correct query string.

Comment: You should put "action-argument"  like action: save_subscriber in the  $.ajax-call, NOT in the data-parameter.

Comment: Well the action is there, so there shouldn't be any difference, no? I mean it works (AJAX)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'll just duplicate the current form with different ID and action pointing to a different URL then hide it populating it automatically based on  firs form, then silently submit it on Success response of first form Ajax request,

But yeah, If you need to POST URL using CURL-PHP without any form this example code below will probably do, I hook it on your current function.

```
function save_subscriber() {
    if (isset($_POST['subscriber_email']) && is_email($_POST['subscriber_email'])) {
        global $wpdb;
        $post_data = array(
            'post_type' => 'subscribers',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );
        $published_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
        add_post_meta($published_id, 'subscriber_email', $_POST['subscriber_email']);

        #Run CURL
        $url = 'http://www.anpdm.com/public/process-subscription-form.aspx'; // URL to be Posted
        $request = curl_init(); //open connection
        curl_setopt_array( $request, array (
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $_REQUEST, /* Since your form is already serialize, you don't need to build query string*/
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($request); // Execute Curl
        $response_data = curl_getinfo($request); // Array of curl response info
        curl_close($request); // Close Connection

        #END CURL

        #$out = $response; // push curl response on Ajax Submit response
        $out = $response_data['http_code']; /* 200 will be the value of this for successfully curl request, you can just replace your Ajax success code with 200 instead of OK or just ignore the response, though its better to know if curl request is successful*/
    } else{
        $out = 'ERROR';
    }
    die($out);
}
```

Testing

```
$url = 'http://www.anpdm.com/public/process-subscription-form.aspx'; 
$request = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt_array( $request, array (
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "id=noID&value=novalue",
));
$response = curl_exec($request); 
$response_data = curl_getinfo($request); 
curl_close($request);
print_r( $response_data );
```

$response_data OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://www.anpdm.com/public/process-subscription-form.aspx
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 222
    [request_size] => 180
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.546
    [namelookup_time] => 0.515
    [connect_time] => 0.843
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.843
    [size_upload] => 21
    [size_download] => 13048
    [speed_download] => 8439
    [speed_upload] => 13
    [download_content_length] => 13048
    [upload_content_length] => 21
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.203
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 89.234.52.177
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => 192.168.254.8
    [local_port] => 53736
)
```

Comment: This looks like something I'd need, I'm just wondering if there is a way to push my curl response on submit differently? The `$out` variable is used on `success` method in my AJAX to notify that everything went ok.

Comment: if your curl request is successful it supposed to response with ```OK``` you can put it outside your ```if``` statement, but it must be inside the function you are targeting via ajax or else it won't trigger,

Comment: I didn't know it will be 'OK', if that's the case that's great :) I'll test this out.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand your code and thought that the URL ```http://www.anpdm.com/public/process-subscription-form.aspx``` will respond ```OK``` when there's a successful post request, which I realize is not the case, You need to setup a response on your ```aspx``` page (which I have no Idea how) that says OK for ```$_REQUEST``` with ```subscriber_email``` query, like for php you can do something like  ```if( isset( $_REQUEST['subscriber_email'] ) { die('OK'); }```

Comment: In the `response_data` I don't see `http_code` key :\ There is: `http://www.anpdm.com/public/process-subscription-form.aspx?formId=xxxxxxxxx, text/html; charset=utf-8, 200, 247, 250, -1, 0, 0, 0.08682, 0.004248, 0.019452, 0.019504, 1454, 13440, 154803, 16747, 13440, 1454, 0.038442, 0, Array, 89.234.52.177, 80, 10.0.0.180, 50391, ` Btw, when I tried to put response as output, I got error message from them, so I think my form could be wrong. I need to see this further.

Comment: the response will output whatever will be displayed on the url you are requesting curl, like if you open ```http://www.anpdm.com/public/process-subscription-form.aspx?formId=xxxxxxxxx``` on a webpage, whatever will be displayed on that will be curl response, ```$response_data``` which is supposed to be the  ```curl_getinfo($request);``` supposed to be an array of response information, I'm not sure, but based on your above comments, it looks like the response has been imploded separated with comma. I can even see ```200``` in there which is suppose to be the ```http_code```

Comment: did run a quick curl test on my local server with simple Ajax, Posted the response above,

Comment: I guess that my response is like that, and I get the 200. I've added the query string (according to my form) but the subscription isn't going through the server. I'll mark this as a resolved, because the curl works, but something with APSIS is to blame...